# Can the type checker help me out here? With type families, maybe?

Tags: haskell, types

So I'm writing this little [soccer game](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Rasenschach) for some time now, and there's one thing that bugs me from the very beginning. The game follows the [Yampa Arcade](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/yampa-arcade.pdf) pattern, so there's a sum type for the "objects" in the game:

```
data ObjState = Ball Id Pos Velo
              | Player Id Team Number Pos Velo
              | Game Id Score
```

Objects react to messages, so there's another sum type:

```
data Msg = BallMsg BM
         | PlayerMsg PM
         | GameMsg GM
data BM = Gained | Lost
data PM = GoTo Position | Shoot
data GM = GoalScored | BallOutOfBounds
```

The Yampa framework relies on so-called signal functions. In our case, there are signal functions for ball, player and game behaviour. Crudely simplified:

```
ballObj, playerObj, gameObj :: (Time -> (GameInput, [Msg])) 
                               -> (Time -> (ObjState, [(Id, Msg)]))
```

So e.g. ballObj takes a function that yields the GameInput (key strokes, game state, ...) and a list of messages specifically for the ball at any given time, and returns a function that yields the ball's state and it's messages to other objects (ball, game, players) at any given time. In Yampa, the type signature actually looks a little nicer:

```
ballObj, playerObj, gameObj :: SF (GameInput, [Msg]) (ObjState, [(Id, Msg)])
```

This uniform type signature is important for the Yampa framework: (again, very crudely simplified) it builds a big signal function from a list of 11 + 11 (players) + 1 (ball) + 1 (game) signal functions with the same type (via dpSwitch) that it then runs (via reactimate).

So now, what bugs me: It only makes sense to send a BallMsg to a Ball, or a PlayerMsg to a Player. If ever someone sends for instance a GameMsg to a Ball, the program will crash. Isn't there a way to get the type checker in position to avoid this? I recently read this nice [Pokemon](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/pick-of-the-week/type-families-and-pokemon) post on type families, and it seems like there is some analogy. So maybe this might be a starting point:

```
class Receiver a where
  Msg a :: *
  putAddress :: Msg a -> a -> Msg a

data BallObj = ...
data GameObj = ...
data PlayerObj = ...

instance Receiver BallObj where
  Msg BallObj = Gained | Lost
(...)
```

Now, the SF function might look something like this:

```
forall b . (Receiver a, Receiver b) => SF (GameInput, [Msg a]) (a, [(b, Msg b)])
```

Will this get me anywhere?

Comment: Relax. Haskell programs cannot crash because of type errors (unless you use unsafe or foreign code). Do you have working code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It crashes because of non-exhaustive patterns in the functions the process the messages.

Comment: Ah, that kind of crash.

Comment: I think since all messages are broadcast to all objects (is this true?), any object should simply ignore any message not intended for it.

Comment: No, messages are sent to a specific receiver. It is still an option to just ignore invalid messages, I just think that I might do better.

Comment: You can implement the constraints with type families or even (multi-param) type classes, but it wouldn't help you with having a single dispatch function to route all your messages. You still end up needing a sum type of all messages and objects, because you can't have a heterogeneous collection. You could use additional type tricks to make the creation of these things look nice, but ultimately you'll end up using some type constraints to get compile time check for message sending, and some sum type for centralized message processing.

Comment: Given a `[Msg]`, how does the framework know which message goes to which object?

Comment: @nm: the message routing is not part of Yampa, each object has an id, messages take the id and a routing function sorts out who gets which message.

Comment: OK so you have some kind of map from IDs to objects, and a function that implements it. Cannot that function fail if you pass a bad ID to it? This is not too different from a failed pattern match. There's a seemingly unavoidable runtime check. Why not make the same function check object types too?

Comment: @yiding: I fear you might be right, that this is not a good fit for what static typing can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the first glance one major problem with your design stands out: you unite completely different entities `Ball`, `Player` and `Game` under a single type. If you need a union type over those entities, go the same way you have with the messages by making them separate types, i.e.:

```
data AnyObject = AnyObjectBall Ball
               | AnyObjectPlayer Player
               | AnyObjectGame Game
```

This way you'll be able to express both the specific functions (`Ball -> BallMsg -> ...`) and general ones (`AnyObject -> AnyMsg -> ...`).

But if I understand your problem correctly, I think I have a solution for you which does not require union types:

```
class Signal object message where
  signal :: SF (GameInput, [message]) (object, [(Id, message)])

data Ball = Ball Id Pos Velo
data BallMsg = BallMsgGained | BallMsgLost
instance Signal Ball BallMsg where
  -- ...

-- so on for Player and Game
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be something along these lines. There needs to be some kind of functional dependency or type family relation between object and message, though, and I think I need to tuple up the message with the receiving object in the result of the SF. It still might not work or look very clumsy, because at the end of the day the message generation and dispatch has a dynamic nature that might not fit with static typing anyway. If I ever manage something I'll share it here!

Comment: @martingw If the type of message or object is defined in runtime, than no fundeps, type-families nor any other type-level programming feature can ever help you. In this scenario I suggest sticking to pattern-matching with functions of type `AnyObject -> AnyMsg -> ...`.

Comment: I think there is a chance for some static typing: For instance, the ball SF constantly measures ball position, and if the ball is out of bounds, it may send an "out of bounds" message to the game SF, and a "you're not in possession anymore" message to the player who currently has the ball. Say Game's ID is 2 and the players's ID is 4, then the Ball SF returns a list [(2, OutOfBounds), (4, DropPossession)]. And if I mix up the numbers, the program will crash. It might do with something like [(Game, OutOfBounds), (Player, DropPossession)] with a fundep between Object and Message type...

Comment: @martingw What about just extending the `AnyMsg` type to include the info you put out into the tuple (the id or whatever)? I mean `data AnyMsg = ABallMsg Id BallMsg | ...` and use just `AnyMsg` instead of `(Id, AnyMsg)`.

Comment: Nikita, the following in your proposal that does not fit my problem: You have the type variable message in the first argument and in the second of SF, implying they are equal. But the type of the first message directly depends on object (Ball SF can only only process ball messages), while the second message can be a message to any kind of object. Hence I find you need fundeps to tackle the first issue, and tuple up object and message to tackle the second.

Answer (score 2):

Skimming the yampa arcade paper it seems like you have a `route` function drawn from their example.

My suggestion would be you alter `route` so it doesn't take a single list of objects, but instead a single game object, a single ball object, and a collection of player objects. Then have

```
data BallMsg = ...
data PlayerMsg = ...
data GameMsg = ...

data AnyMsg = ABallMsg BallMsg
            | APlayerMsg PlayerMsg
            | AGameMsg GameMsg
```

Now `route` works on a uniform `AnyMsg` but it dispatches them to the right destination depending on their contents.

Comment: Thanks for the input! My code is already organized kind of like you suggest, the problem is I don't get the type checker to prevent illegal object / msg combinations at compile time. I think I have to rephrase my question, I can see it's not really clear what I want.